# Mapping textures to 2 triangles in roblox

Tags: lua, mesh, roblox

I am currently trying to map textures using image labels onto 2 different triangles (because im using right angle wedges so i need 2 to make scalene triangles), but here is the problem, I can only set positional, size, and rotational data so I need to figure out how I can use this information to correctly map the texture onto the triangle
[image: example]
the position is based on the topleft corner and size of triangle (<1,1> corner is at the bottom right and <0,0> corner is at top left) and the size is based on triangle size also (<1,1> is same size as triangle and <0,0> is infinitely tiny) and rotation is central based.
I have the UV coordinates (given 0-1) and face vertices, all from an obj file. The triangles in 3D are made up of 2 wedges which are split at a right angle from the longest surface and from the opposite angle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand this however it may be help to change the canvas properties on the Surface GUI